# How can I support decrypting an encrypted string to be added into my request header, but still log my request header showing the encrypted string?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

How can I support decrypting an encrypted string to be added into my request header, but still log my request header showing the encrypted string?

What currently happens is:

```
password = b'bXlwYXNzd29yZCE=' #this is b64, pretend its stronger
password = decode(password)  # fake func for illustration

authorization = 'NLAuth nlauth_account=1111111,nlauth_email=' + username + ',nlauth_signature=' + password + ',nlauth_role=' + role
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.add_header('Authorization', authorization)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')

logging.debug(req.headers)
```

> [Console Output] {'Authorization': 'NLAuth
>   nlauth_account=1111111,nlauth_email=my@emailaddress,nlauth_signature=mypassword!,nlauth_role=3',
>   'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

What I want is:

> [Console Output] {'Authorization': 'NLAuth
>   nlauth_account=1111111,nlauth_email=my@emailaddress,nlauth_signature=b'bXlwYXNzd29yZCE=',nlauth_role=3',
>   'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

The web service requires a string value in the Authorization header, passing in any encrypted string will cause authentication to fail - so decoding at request time is required, however this does not mean I want it decoded in my log files or to console.

Answer (score 0):

create a temporary object from your req.headers then pass this to logging.debug().

```
_ = {}
for k,v in req.headers.items():
  v = k == 'Authorization' and re.sub('nlauth_signature=([^,]+)',\
                                      repr(original_password),\
                                      v) or v
  _[k]=v

logging.debug(_)
```

it would be better however if you simply put "<masked>" instead of original_password in the re.sub() call